# Showing Pages Like A Blog with Multiple Categories (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

So here's what I'm trying to do: 69.89.31.103/~infoconc/solutions-that-fit/

On that page, I have a list of categories on the side.  There are a whole bunch of pages which are under those categories.  When you click on the category link, I need a template that smartly decides which category you're in - and only displays the code from there.

What I have right now is this:

```
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query('post_type=page&showposts=&cat=id&paged=' . $paged);
```

I think another line needs to go after the `cat=` but I don't know what to put there to make it dynamically read categories and google isn't helping. :(

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to reinvent the wheel ;) Just add archive.php file to your theme. This template just needs to contain standard loop plus get_header(), get_footer(), get_sidebar() and other stuff your index.php or page.php already contains. WordPress will decide on specific category itself.

Anyway, read something about [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), [theme developement](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and about [template hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

It's worth reading and will save you a lot of time.